# Google Maps crashes with Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17d280e0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

Google Maps SDK version: 2.0.1

iOS version: 9.3.x, 9.2.x 7.0.x

ARC enabled.

**Crash stack**:
Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17d280e0> was mutated while being enumerated

```
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2501c10b __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x247c2e17 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2501bb91 -[NSException name]
3  MyApp                          0x18e1b5 -[GMSVectorMapView buildVisibleAccessibilityItems]
4  MyApp                          0x2a2d13 -[GMSMapView updateOverlay:]ssfsdf
5  MyApp                          0x2dc04f -[GMSOverlay setMap:]
6  MyApp                          0xce87b __25-[VCMain updateMarkersOnMap]_block_invoke (VCMain.m:1186)
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x24b95b5b _dispatch_call_block_and_release
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x24ba4921 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x24ba4305 _dispatch_worker_thread3
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24d53b29 (Missing)
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24d53718 (Missing)
```

This crash occurs when performing following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0 {
    NSArray *coordinates = [networkClient getCoordinates];
    for (NSDictionary *coord in coordinates) {

        double double_lat = [[coord objectForKey:@"geoy"] doubleValue];
        double double_long = [[coord objectForKey:@"geox"] doubleValue];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(double_lat, double_long);

        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:location];
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image"];
        marker.title = title;
        marker.snippet = subtitle;
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        marker.map = mapMainGoogle; // crash
    }

}
```

Also my application executes the following code:

```
[mapMainGoogle clear];
```

I tried to put [GMSMarker setMap] and [GMSMapView clear] methods in @synchronized(mapMainGoogle) or NSLock lock/unlock. But it doesn't help and crash still appears.

When I put this methods inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_qeueue()) block, it randomly crashes with the following crash:

**Crash stack:**
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22a43a86 objc_msgSend + 5
1  MyApp                          0x18f6d7 -[NSThread(GTMBlocksAdditions) GMSx_gtm_performBlock:] + 1435351
2  MyApp                          0x2a3025 -[GMSMarker displayLayer:] + 360140
3  QuartzCore                     0x258dca83 CA::Layer::display() + 106
4  MyApp                          0x2dbda5 -[GMSMarkerLayer display] + 592972
5  QuartzCore                     0x258c0f0d CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 208
6  QuartzCore                     0x258c0bc5 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
7  QuartzCore                     0x258c0081 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 368
8  QuartzCore                     0x258bfd55 CA::Transaction::commit() + 520
9  QuartzCore                     0x258eda73 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*) + 310
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x22fab905 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 508
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x22fab507 _pthread_exit + 86
12 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x22faae21 _pthread_wqthread + 1044
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x22faa9fc start_wqthread + 8
```

Please any suggestions.

Comment: What if you made a copy of the array before enumerating it? E.g. `NSArray *coordinates = [[networkClient getCoordinates] copy];`. I'm assuming that's the array that's changing underneath the enumeration.

Comment: I just tried to add copy method, but it doesn't help. The same crash occurs.

Comment: try to put the whole loop in a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_qeueue()) block

Answer (score 0):

The error message told you exactly what's wrong: An array gets modified while you enumerate it. This is improved for example by using immutable arrays. The "@synchronized" cannot help since you are iterating in a background thread which will have no idea of that @synchronized.

Comment: In my code there is no array with elements of type GMSMarker.  Every marker creates, setups its properties, displays (with [GMSMarker setMap]) and destroys inside for-in loop.